# Upgrading my combobox

Tags: extjs

One question about searching data using ExtJS combobox.
Now everything works, but when i wrote a name in combobox i have to press refresh in paging toolbar at the bottom to fetch the data i am looking for. How to make it refresh automatically when i wrote something like MAR

```
{ 

                xtype: 'combobox',          
                queryMode: 'local',
                valueField: 'id',
                fieldLabel: 'Book:',
                name: 'book_fk',
                typeAhead: false,
                hidenTrigger: true,
                hidenLabel: true,
                pageSize: 10,               
                width: 400,
                padding: 5,
                store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',
                        {
                            fields: ['id','book','name_author'],
                            autoLoad: true, 
                            pageSize: 10,                       
                            proxy:
                            {
                                type: 'ajax',
                                url: 'book/load',
                                reader:
                                {
                                    type: 'json',
                                    root: 'data',
                                    totalProperty: 'total'
                                }
                            }
                        }),

                listConfig: 
                {
                    loadingText: 'Searching...',
                    emptyText: 'No matching posts found.',

                    getInnerTpl: function() 
                    {
                        return '<a class="search-item" href="book/load?t={topicId}&p={id}"></a>' +
                            '<span>{book}</span> {name_author}' 
                            '{excerpt}'; //+
                        //'</a>';
                    }

                }, 

                displayTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
                                        '<tpl for=".">',
                                            '{book} - {name_author}',
                                        '</tpl>'
                                        )


            },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to set the [queryMode](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-queryMode) of the combobox to remote.